# Would you say, "She was quiet after she'd been back from school," or "She was quiet after she'd gotten back from school"?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-perfect, got-gotten, would-have-been

I don't know if these two choices are just preference or not.

On a side note, would it sound better if you say "ever since" or "since" in place of the word "after"?

thanks

Comment: There is no need for the past perfect tense. As a British English speaker, I would say _She was quiet after she came back/got back from school_. _Since_ is only appropriate if you are speaking from the perspective of later that day - _She has been quiet since she came back from school_.

Comment: @KateBunting This seems to me a perfect answer - why not post it as such? I might just add that the use of *since* would only be appropriate if the quietness still existed at the time the person was speaking.  Otherwise the past perfect would be required. e.g. *When I saw the family last night, she had been quiet since she (had) returned from school.*

Answer (score 1):

The simpler option is often the better option. Why complicate a sentence unnecessarily with the past perfect "after she'd been back"? Here is a simpler sentence:

> After she returned from school, she was quiet.

If you were to add an extra time element to your sentence, however, it could be written using the past perfect, as in the following sentence:

> After she had been back from school for three hours, she was quiet. [In other words, perhaps for three hours she was quite boisterous and outspoken, but when three hours had elapsed, she grew silent. The poor girl was probably talked out!]

Comment: But *After she returned from school she was quiet*, carries different emphasis and hence alternative meaning to *She was quiet after she got back from school*. They do not amount to the same thing. Suppose the sentence was in response to an observation *Jane's quiet this evening!* Your sentence would not be the most natural expression.